# Deformation theory about filtered sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, algebraic-stacks

I am reading the paper “ Components of the stack of torsion-free sheaves of rank 2 on ruled surfaces” by C.Walter.

In the proof of Lemma 4.1(a) ,in $Filtcoh(X)$ and an object $F_1 \subset F$ the tangent space for automorphism of $F_1 \subset F$ (resp.the tangent space of deformation of $F_1 \subset F$ ,resp. the obstruction of the deformation of $F_1 \subset F$ ) is $Ext_{-}^0(F,F)$(resp. $Ext_{-}^1(F,F)$, resp. $Ext_{-}^2(F,F)$)

But , in appendix to chapter 2 of  “Geometry of moduli spaces of sheave” by Huybrechts and  Lehn,I found the tangent space of deformation of $F_1 \subset F$(resp.obstruction of deformation of $F_1 \subset F$) is $Ext_{+}^0(F,F)$ (resp. $Ext_{+}^1(F,F)$)(Remark:nothing is written about the tangent space of automorphisms in it.)

Which is true and why ?